# Filtering a Firestore Fetch, Need to make sure that status != cancel

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Im trying to filter my Firestore get, To check for bookings that dont have a status of cancel.

But It doesn't seem to work with anything that doesn't equate to true

Ive tried 2 things as far:

```
 getEntry() {
    return this.firestore.collection('doc', x => x.where('status', '!=', 'cancel')).snapshotChanges();
  }
```

```
 Entry: Entrymodel;
  entries: Entrymodel[] = [];

  ngOnInit(){
    this.entryservice.getEntry().subscribe(data => {
      this.entries = data.map(e => {
        return {
          id: e.payload.doc.id,
          ...e.payload.doc.data() as {}
        } as Entrymodel;
      })
    });
    return this.entries.filter(i => i.status == "cancel");
  }
```

I suspect because the Fetch returns the below return doesnt get reached..

Comment: What do you mean with "To check for bookings that dont have a status of cancel." Do you have a `status`field in all bookings? Or you want to get the bookings that don't have a `status` field?

Comment: In addition, are you 100% sure that the != operator is supporter by angularfire? I’m not at all a specialist of angularfire but I don’t see anything about this operator in the release notes.

Comment: I have a status field on all bookings im trying to filter out the cancelled bookings from the fetch(The field only holds Attending|Cancel)  And no I am not As far as I can see it only works with filters that equate to true, Thus why I thought id come ask maybe someone knows a kind of work around

Comment: What version of AngularFire are you using? The operator functionality is a functionality of Firestore lauched on last september, so your version of AngularFire might not support it yet, try upgrading both the Firestore and AngularFire to their latest versions and it might be fixed. Let me know if this worked.

Comment: I updated everything and kinda realized That despite it still not working im just not that smart, and if I Just actually used my brain id realize that, Just saying ```'==', 'Attending' ```Is the exact same thing as what im trying to achieve here

Comment: @BeepBopImaRobot Can you share the solution you came up with by using an equality instead of an inequality as an answer so that others in the community can refer to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to get all the entries who are not "canceled"

I just looked for the ones that have the opposite A.K.A

Everything that has a attending status instead of trying to check for a negative which it seems firebase doesn't allow for Im just changing the logic to work with a True

```
getAventry(){
    return this.firestore.collection('entry', x => x.where('status' , '==', 'Attending')).snapshotChanges();
  }
```